# calculate power series value at point

Tags: calculus, power-series

I have the following power series
$$
f(x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}x^{2n+1}}{2n-1}
$$ and want to calculate its value at $x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.

I checked the radius of convergence and this power series does converge when $x < 1$.

From here I tried to use the know power series of $\cos(x), \sin(x)$ but wasn't able to get anything useful from it, how can I calculate this? is there any other known power series that can be integrate/derived to get this?

Comment: Do you know the power series of $\arctan$ ?

Comment: unfortunately no, this is part of a university course and I should be able to calculate it only with things they showed us

Comment: Then integrate the power series of $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ to get the one of $\arctan$, and you will recognize something.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n+1}}{2n-1} = \sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+3}}{2k+1} = x^2\arctan x
$$